# How to return JSON object by executing SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, xml, stored-procedures

I am using this method to return a `XML` as result. I need to return a json object after executing the stored procedure. Where should I edit the following code to return a JSON object?

```
public XmlElement GetGraphData(int eventTypeID, int patientID)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetGraphData", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", eventTypeID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", patientID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    con.Close();

    XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
    XmlElement xmlElement = xmldata.DocumentElement;
}
```

Comment: you want to convert dataset to json object . right ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also - you're executing the query **twice** - once on `ExecuteNonQuery`, and a second time on `da.Fill(ds)` - don't do that! What are you trying to do? Load data from the database? Don't use `ExecuteNonQuery` for that! This call is only intended for SQL statements that **don't return** any data! (Like `INSERT`, `DELETE`)

Comment: yes Amey Deshpande .. You are right

Comment: you can use `Newtonsofts Json.Net`

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2016 has FOR JSON clause that formats query result directly in query/stored procedure - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957476.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For return in JSON format Create SP like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetAlluser 

AS
BEGIN
    Select * from AspNetUsers FOR JSON AUTO
END
GO
```

and for get user detail in class obj

```
var UserDetails=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result)
```